# Recurring appointments aren't expanding recurrence using CalendarFolder.FindAppointments in the C# Exchange Web Service API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, recurrence, appointment

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd636179%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), .FindAppointments() expands the recurrence of items:

> Obtains a list of appointments by searching the contents of this
>   folder and performing recurrence expansion for recurring appointments

It's not working:

```
            ExchangeService service = ExchangeServiceUtilities.CreateExchangeService(s,u);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            CalendarView cv = new CalendarView(now, now);

            CalendarFolder cal = CalendarFolder.Bind(service,WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
            FindItemsResults<Appointment> apps = cal.FindAppointments(cv);
            Trace.WriteLine(apps.TotalCount);
            foreach (Appointment a in apps)
            {
                a.Load();
                Trace.WriteLine(a.IsRecurring);
                Trace.WriteLine("Checking: " + a.End.ToString() + " : " + now);
                if (a.End > now)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("Setting Appointment for: " + u.Id);
                    ScheduleAppointment(a,u);
                }
            }
```

produces the following:

```
1
True
Checking: 6/24/2013 10:00:00 PM : 6/24/2013 9:41:12 PM
Setting Appointment for: 6dd36837d202bf28b0a8cfece47fb111cd0fec04
```

It's set to recur every half hour, so I should be seeing a lot more of them...

I figured out what was wrong: **As it turns out, there is a bug in the method which causes it not to expand appointments if your start and end date are the same. Thanks M$.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there is a bug in the method which causes it not to expand appointments if your start and end date are the same.  Thanks M$.

Comment: Glad you found it. Can you include a reference to the M$ fact in your own answer and then mark it as the correct answer (you have to wait 2 days for that)?